# Direct sum of vector subspaces - necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question is related to these two questions.

[Difference between sum and direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163318/difference-between-sum-and-direct-sum)

[Examples of sum and direct sum of vector subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242563/examples-of-sum-and-direct-sum-of-vector-subspaces)

I am going through a book and I managed to prove two necessary and sufficient conditions for a sum of vector subspaces

$$V_1 + V_2 + ... V_s$$ to be direct sum $V_1 \bigoplus V_2 \bigoplus ... \bigoplus V_s \tag{*}$

The first one is this:

(1) For every $i$:
$$V_i \cap (V_1 + V_2 + V_{i-1} + ... V_{i+1} + ... V_s) = \{0\}$$

The second one is this:

(2) The **zero vector** can be represented as sum of vectors from $V_i$ in a unique way
(namely $0\ =\ 0\ +\ 0 +\ \dots +\ 0$).

These two were given as problems in my book.

Now... I wonder if the following one is also a necessary and sufficient condition for the same thing

(3)  $V_i \cap (\cup_{j \ne i} V_j) = \{0\}$

I tried but I cannot prove that from the third one it follows $(*)$.
Maybe this third condition is just not enough to prove $(*)$?

Or am I just not seeing how to use (3) to prove (*)?

This third condition is **not in my book** but I somehow felt it's also a necessary and sufficient condition for $(*)$ so I tried to prove it. But I could not do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\Bbb R^2$, take$$V_1=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\},\ V_2=\{(0,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}\text{ and }V_3=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}.$$Then $V_1+V_2+V_3$ is not a direct sum (for instance, $(0,0)=(1,0)+(0,1)-(1,1)$), but, for each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$,$$V_i\cap\left(\bigcup_{j\ne i}V_j\right)=\{0\}.$$

Comment: Hm... Nice example, thanks. I want to make sure I understand you properly. So basically these are 3 lines (1-dimensional subspaces) through the origin of the 2d space $\Bbb R^2$. Correct? They satisfy (3) but their sum is not direct. Is their sum equal to $\Bbb R^2$ actually? Seems it is, right?

Comment: Yes to everything. In particular, since $V_1+V_2=\Bbb R^2$, $V_1+V_2+V_3$ is also equal to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I see. Thanks again.

Comment: ...whereas $\bigcup_i V_i$ is just a star-shaped region in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is not convex and thus not a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

The third condition is not sufficient. Consider $V_1=\{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\}$, $V_2=\{(x,x):x\in\Bbb R\}$, and $V_2=\{(0,x):x\in\Bbb R\}$. Then $V_1\cap(V_2\cup V_3)=\{(0,0)\}$, but $\Bbb R^2\neq V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3$.